# Why I am getting blank response on ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

How can I check if the response is blank? 
I tried doing this but it's not working:

```js
$.ajax({
          url: 'http://localhost/sample.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: ({name: fname}),
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(response){
                  if( response == null || response == ""){
                     //do something
                  }
          }
});
```

Comment: may be it is having blank spaces so try `!response || response.trim() == ""`

Comment: Developer tools (F12 on most decent browsers) - most have a network tab where you can inspect raw traffic - that should show you what is being returned exactly

Comment: Check the Developer Tools. Could be something in your php file rather than your javascript file

Comment: Show your serverside code for sample.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty json string is denoted by "{}", not "". Hence if your server sends "", I don't think the success callback will trigger. And if the server actually sends "{}", then you need to modify your conditional.

Comment: You're right. I should have put "error: function()" it catch the blank response. Problem solved. :) Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

you can check for the length of the response

```
$.ajax({
          url: 'http://localhost/sample.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: ({name: fname}),
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(response){
                  if( response != null || !response.length > 0){
                     //do something
                  }
          }
});
```

what are you passing with the fname variable?

Answer (score 0):

Usually even a blank response will have a space in it. Try removing all spaces using

```
if(reponse.replace(/\s/g,'') == '') ...
```